# Espresso pauses on an activity started from a third party library

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am trying to do some ui testing using espresso, but when it gets into an activity that is created through the library, the espresso does not do anything. It looks like the espresso pauses and waits until the library activity finishes and resumes the rest commands.

**Test Class:**

Here is what I have for the test class.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest{

  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule =
    new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

  @Test
  public void startTest) throws Exception {
    // starts KEYBOARD_ACTIVITY
    onView(withId(R.id.button_start)).perform(click());

    // test pauses here!!

    // pressBack supposed to go back to MainActivity,
    // but this doesnt do anything either
    // pressBack();

    // click random coordinates several times
    onView(withId(R.id.KEYBOARDAREA)).perform(clickXY(randomCoordinates));


    // This supposed to finish the KEYBOARD_ACTIVITY and go back to MainActivity
    onView(withId(R.id.button_done)).perform(click());

  }
```

The problem is that the test pauses right after *button_start* clicked and if I don't do anything, test fails within a minute or so by timeout (?), Or if I quit the KEYBOARD_ACTIVITY, the test resumes, and puts nullpointer exception error since R.id.KEYBORDAREA is gone.

**About Library:**

I have MainActivity with a button that starts a new activity using the following code in the MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = KEYBOARD_ACTIVITY.makeIntent(MainActivity.this, params);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST);
```

Since the .aar library, which is already added as a module dependency, creates an activity by itself with the params, I do not have the activity class file inside the project; instead, I add *activity* in AndroidManifest.xml just like adding other activities. During the Keyboard activity, the user is supposed to touch the keypad and finally tap "finish", then the result goes back to MainActivity and shows the result.

The library is composed with some C files using jni, which encrypts the user input, and Java codes that handles appearances, parameters, activities, etc.

**What I've done so far:**

1. I tried to start testing from the KEYBOARD_ACTIVITY by having the Rule:

   @Rule
   public ActivityTestRule activityTestRule =
       new ActivityTestRule<>(KEYBOARDACTIVITY.class)

But it gives nullPointerException error saying *attempt to invoke virtual method*.

2. I tried UiAutomator as well but it paused and resumed just like espresso did.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Like espresso doing nothing on an activity called from external library?
Or does anyone know anything about espresso's levels of access authority of other activities, if such thing exists? Or maybe there is such thing like espresso's "focus" of testing activity.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?  I have a similar issue.